# Update table getting values from three joining tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, multiple-tables, sql-server-2022

I was trying to run an update for the table `INVOICE.field1 = RECEIPT.field1`, however there is no direct relationship between `INVOICE` and `RECEIPT`, but by the `PURCHASE` table that contains relations with both tables. I am using SQL Server 2022.

Below options don't work:

```
UPDATE INVOICE T1
SET T1.field1 = T3.field1
FROM PURCHASE T2 
INNER JOIN RECEIPT T3 ON T2.field2 = T3.field2 
WHERE T1.field3 = T2.field3 
  AND T1.field1 IN ('x')
```

or

```
UPDATE INVOICE T1
JOIN PURCHASE T2 ON T2.field2 = T3.field2 
JOIN RECEIPT T3 ON T1.field3 = T2.field3
SET T1.field1 = T3.field1
WHERE T1.field1 IN ('x')
```

or

```
UPDATE INVOICE T1, PURCHASE T2, RECEIPT T3 
SET T1.field1 = T3.field1
WHERE T1.field3 = T2.field3 
  AND T2.field2 = T3.field2
  AND T1.field1 IN ('x')
```

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't a helpful problem statement and could mean anything. Does it mean you get an error? Unexpected results? Undesired behaviour? A server crash? Your washing machine stops working? Though`UPDATE INVOICE T1` isn't valid syntax; it's `UPDATE <Object Name>` or `UPDATE <Object Alias>`. I suspect the syntax is the root of your problem.

Comment: Relational database tables don't have *fields* - they have **columns** ...

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) shows clearly the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the following syntax:

```sql
UPDATE t /*alias of the table to update*/
SET someField = t2.someOtherField
FROM TABLE1 t /*the table with the above alias */
INNER JOIN TABLE3 t3 
   ON t3.ID = t.ID
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
   ON t2.ID = t3.ANOTHER_ID
```

This way you can build your joins as needed and just refer to correct table in the beginning of the UPDATE.

Comment: Prefer? Isn't that the only syntax?

Comment: I *suppose* you could repeat the object name in the `UPDATE` clause instead, @DaleK . SQL Server *should* be clever enough to know that it's the same "instance" of the table (aliased as `t`), but I wouldn't recommend leaving it to chance; effectively "Yes, it's the only syntax".

Comment: There are some ugly alternatives, for example by using WHERE EXISTS and some other funky old school JOINs one can use.